# Can't figure out the types of clauses in these sentences

Tags: clauses, subordinate-clauses

Please help me to define types of clauses **1) main/independent** 2) **subject,object, predicative, adverbial...**

> La Falterona began to sing, in an undertone, but as she heard the
>   sounds come from her lips and found that they were clear and pure she
>   let herself go.

**`La Falterona began to sing, in an undertone`** - independent.
"**`she let herself go`**" - also independent.

And what about subbordinate clauses "**`as she heard the sounds come from her lips`**" and "**`found that they were clear and pure`**" - what do they depend on?

And one more thing.**"Go"** in "let herself **go**" is a verbal (simple infinitive)?

Comment: *She let herself go* is an independent clause coordinated (with *but*) with the other independent clause *La Falterona began to sing*.

Comment: These two clauses are coordinated with *and*. Depending on your grammatical sect (or that of you teachers) , you may understand them as a) the conjoint clausal object of the preposition *as* or b) a conjoint clause subordinated by the conjunction *as*.

Comment: Ok. But what are they dependent on? On "she let herself go"?

Comment: @Daisy: He sat at the table ready to eat, but as he picked up the bowl  and found that it was hot he burnt his hands. Does the as-clause go with the sitting or with the getting burnt?

Comment: [ **La Falterona began to sing**, [ in an undertone ] ], **but** [ [ as [ she heard the sounds come from her lips ] and [ found that they were clear and pure ] ] **she let herself go** ].

Comment: As far as *go*, yes it is an infinitive. The same can be seen in "let (something/somebody) *be*", "let (something) *rip/loose/slide/slip/fall*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this diagram will help. Coordinating conjunctions are capitalized, and arrows point from modifiers to the underlined element modified:

```
 (La Falterona began to sing 
 (                      ‾‾↑‾
 (                        in an undertone, 
 (BUT 
 (             (heard the sounds come from her lips 
 (     as she -(AND 
 (     ↓       (found that they were clear and pure 
 (_____↓____________
 (she let herself go.
```

*let herself go* means "allowed herself to sing loudly".